# error in logcat "Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type"

Tags: java, android, ios, arrays, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase under uid. I get an error  logcat

> Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type

Codes:

```
    recview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recview);
    recview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference uidRef = db.child("Users").child(uid);

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
                    .setQuery(uidRef, model.class)
                    .build();

    adapter=new myadapter(options);
    recview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**This is db.i am trying to retreive filename**

```
    {
  "Users": {
    "NseKqjViW4XO2RshRGQ7kW1swbv2": {
      "-NE4twoPdj2ZiypGd2D-": {
        "filename": "Math"
      },
      "-NE57EGP7DbgRll3yvlJ": {
        "filename": "Science"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your database json ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond using @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `query`. You can try this.

```
//DatabaseReference uidRef = db.child("Users").child(uid);
final Query query = db.child("Users").child(uid);
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
   .setQuery(query, model.class)
   .build();
```

Comment: Sorry for this problem. I changed db structure now

Comment: @UniqueIdea have you solved the problem ?

Comment: yes i solved i changed db structure.thanks a lot for help me sir